# Korean character issue when using ORACLE US7ASCII character set

Tags: php, oracle-call-interface

Korean character issue when using ORACLE US7ASCII character set in PHP

This is my connection String

```
$link = oci_connect("test", "test", "//localhost/xe",'US7ASCII');
```

Below is my json

```
success": true,
    "data": [
        {
            "INDT": "11\/05\/2017 09:02:00",
            "no": 1,
            "color": "Black",
            "SUTM": "09:00",
            "name": "Bear geals",
            "id": "53716695",
            "gend": "M",
            "age": "67y",
            "docotorname": "???",
            "add": "?? ??? ????"
        },
```

What is the issue, what should i do?

Comment: Korean character  are in "???" mark

Answer (score 1):

`US7ASCII` character set does not include Korean characters. You need to use unicode instead like `AL32UTF8`.

Comment: but the Data is added in Korean characters with US7ASCII character set